# Failed to convert value(s) to axis units' - while creating a plot for a df

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am pretty new to python. I am trying to create a bar plot for data in 2 columns of a df.

```
product = df1['Product Name']
sales = df1['Total Sales']

df1.nlargest(5, 'Total Sales').plot.bar(xticks= df1['Product Name'])
```

gives me an error ending with:

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units:                                            Product Name  \
5                         12 Colour Holbein Set - Basic   
6            12 x 1 ml Pan - White - 6.2 x 4.7 x 0.7 cm   
7                        18 Colour Holbein Set - Floral   
8                          18 Colour Starter Set - UMAE   
9     24 x 0.5 ml Pan - Transparent - 7.5 x 4.9 x 0....   
...                                                 ...
```

Interestingly the plot is created (see below) just the x-axis has no labels.

Do I need to do any reformating before I can plot the data with correct x-axis?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJvpA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the ticks. Just tell `df.plot.bar()` what the x- and y-variables should be:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name': ['spam', 'bacon', 'eggs', 'cheese'], 
                    'Total Sales': [123, 99, 155, 144]})

df1.nlargest(3, 'Total Sales').plot.bar(x='Product Name', y='Total Sales')
```

[image: barplot example]